# JHipster Project clearCheckSums on production database

Tags: postgresql, maven, intellij-idea, liquibase, jhipster

After deploying a JHipster project on a production server, I regenerated the project using former .jhipster/*.json files. 
Therefore, liquibase changelog files have been rewritten as well. I have changed a single entity on the newly generated project by adding a field. I wish to use the previous database of the production system.

To test this, I pulled a dump of the production database and imported it into my local Postgres installation. In IntelliJ, I select the production profile (which is configured to use PSQL instead of H2).

When building the application using the production profile, I of course experience liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException's, since the checksums are off.

Thus, I want to regenerate the checksums employing liquibase:clearCheckSums goal. However, the goal only executes on H2.

```
[INFO]     driver: org.h2.Driver
[INFO]     url: jdbc:h2:file:./target/h2db/db/test
[INFO]     username: test
[INFO]     password: ****
[INFO]     use empty password: false
[INFO]     properties file: null
[INFO]     properties file will override? false
[INFO]     prompt on non-local database? true
[INFO]     clear checksums? false
```

Though I require a checksum reset on the production database (Postgres).

What do I have to do to execute on Postgres instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can edit the *liquibase-maven-plugin* in the *pom.xml* file of the project:

```
 <configuration>
 <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml</changeLogFile>
        <driver>[your postgres driver]</driver>
        <url>[url to your db]</url>
        <username>[your username]</username>
        <password>[your password]</password> 
 </configuration>
```

After that you can run from command line the mvn libquibase plugin  like this:
mvn liquibase:clearCheckSums
Now liquibase should work against your database.
cheers, duderoot